# how to make button stay highlighted after click on screen?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added two button in modal window in which one button is highlighted but when-ever i am going to click on screen it goes to normal.How can i make it stay highlighted.
I am using following code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">New</button> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Used</button> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" autofocus>Any</button>
```

---

Comment: Maybe use the :active and :focus pseudoclasses for your button and change them to the background colors you want.

Answer (score 3):

So you want [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cj7efzb9/3/)?

CSS

```
.active {
    color: #F00;
}
```

JS

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('button').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML :

```
<button id="highlight" ..... ></button>
```

CSS :

```
#highlight, #highlight:hover, #highlight:active, #highlight:focus {
    color://any-color;
    // more css
}
```

NOTE : this is using the pseudo classes hover, focus and active, to keep the same style of the button unchanged when any event on the button occurs.

Comment: yes but want to stay unchanged when i will click on remaining part of the screen.

Comment: Yes it will, because of the first selector, #highlight, but remember, this button will have only one style and will not change style on any event no matter what.

Comment: but i don't want to change it after click on screen. how can i do it.It will change only when i will select any other button.

Comment: perhaps you got me wrong on the first answer, i told you that it's won't change at any event including clicking on the screen, why don't you try it and give me a feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var yourbuttons = document.getElementsByClassName('highlight-hover');
for (var i = yourbuttons.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var currentbtn;
    yourbuttons[i].onclick=function(){
         if(currentbtn){
             currentbtn.classList.remove("highlight");
          }
          this.classList.add("highlight");
          currentbtn=this;
    }
};
```

There's not really a css only method if you want the button to stay highlighted when you click another part of the screen. :active or :focus remove their styles when the element is not longer active or in focus

Here's a working version of what it seems you want because i'm bored at work https://jsfiddle.net/mksty8eq/

When you click on one button it stays highlighted until another button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

First setting autofocus inside modal will not work always. You should set focus on button via javascript. Refer http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals .
`$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#button3').focus()
})`

`:focus` and `:active` are pseudo-classes that allows us to define specific CSS rules depending on state of the element. In bootstrap `.active` and `.focus` classes has same CSS style as `:focus` and `:active`. 
So add `.active` or `.focus` to the button that you want to highlight always.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">Any</button>
```

Comment: i don't want to make button always highlighted i just want to make it until i did't  select next button but whenever i click on any where in screen the effect is going to disappear.

Comment: In that case you should capture click event on buttons and remove `active ` class when other buttons are clicked. `$("button").on('click', function(e){ $("button").removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active');})`